# Bash: Sum fields of a line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with the following format:

```
a 1 2 3 4
b 7 8
c 120
```

I want it to be parsed into:

```
a 10
b 15
c 120
```

I know this can be easily done with awk, but I'm not familiar with the syntax and can't get it to work for me.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok simple awk primer:

```
awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { total+=$i }; print $1,total; total=0 }' file
```

NF is an internal variable that is reset on each line and is equal to the number of fields on that line so

for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) starts a for loop starting at 2

total+=$i means the var total has the value of the i'th field added to it. and is performed for each iteration of the loop above.

print $1,total prints the 1st field followed by the contents of OFS variable (space by default) then the total for that line.

total=0 resets the totals var ready for the next iteration.

all of the above is done on each line of input.

For more info see grymoires intro [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: don't you need to add
 total=0
after the print?

Comment: Interesting that you'd init total after the print instead of before the loop - seems counter-intuitive to me but YMMV.

Comment: no need to init variables in awk, so resetting after each iteration works just as well as before.

Comment: yes, it will reset that variable in that script so it produces the correct result but when coding in general it's best to init variables before you use them, not after you use them. It makes the code more easily understandable and as programs grow larger it protects your code from changes to that variable happening between the time when you used it and before you need to use it again.

Answer (score 3):

Start from column two and add them:

```
 awk '{tot=0; for(i=2;i<$NF;i++) tot+=$i; print $1, tot;}' file
```

Comment: The space is superfluous; `print $1,tot` should be enough.

Comment: @cbuckley Yes, removed it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

A pure bash solution:

```
$ while read f1 f2
> do
>   echo $f1 $((${f2// /+}))
> done < file
```

On running it, got:

```
a 10
b 15
c 120
```

The first field is read into variable `f1` and the rest of the fields are i `f2`. In variable `f2` , spaces are replaced in place with `+` and evaluated.

Comment: would fail for various values of either field and, probably, white space that isn't a single blank char between 2nd and subsequent fields.

Comment: The solution is provided for the file which OP has provided.

Comment: That's fine, it's just worth mentioning that it may not work for files other than the posted sample input so the OP gets a heads-up on that as it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tricky way to use a subshell, positional parameters and IFS. Works with various amounts of whitespace between the fields.

```
while read label numbers; do 
    echo $label $(set -- $numbers; IFS=+; bc <<< "$*")
done < filename
```

This works because the shell expands `"$*"` into a single string of the positional parameters joined by the first char of `$IFS` ([documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters))